# SQL all fields with com # (SELECT * FROM)

Tags: sql, excel, hashtag, intersystems-cache

I need run a generic `SQL` query with the character # between each field in the query result so that I can work with in `Excel`. I.E:

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE
```

RESULT

```
NAME#AGE#SALARY#EMAIL 
Bob#59#1700#bob@bob.com
```

How can I to do this?

Comment: Different platforms use different operator for string concatenation. Do you have a specific vendor in mind?

Comment: Sorry, I use the Caché Intersystem Database

Comment: Stuff like that is typically offered by the SQL client's ability to export data

Comment: I am using WinSQL..Do you recommend me another?

Comment: Thank you. I changed the editor. I am using the databasenet free..and all is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Caché you can export data with System Management Portal. You can read how you can do it in the [documentation](https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GSQL_impexp#GSQL_impexp_export).
[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Name + '#' + AGE FROM Employee
```

Or you may need to convert some fields, in MSSQL it looks like:

```
SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), E.Age) + '#')
FROM Employee E
```

**If you cannot specify values:**

```
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(255) = 'Employee'

-- use MAX since this will be a long query
DECLARE @csv VARCHAR(MAX)

-- Create a query containing SELECT CONVERT(varchar(255), COALESCE(columnanme, '')) for all column names, in 1 line
-- COALACE in case a column is null (otherwise result will be 'null'.
SELECT @csv = COALESCE(@csv + 'CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),COALESCE(' + SC.name + ', '''')) + ''#'' + ', '')
FROM sysobjects SO
JOIN syscolumns SC ON SC.id = SO.id
WHERE SO.name = @tableName

-- chop off the last ','
SET @csv = (SELECT LEFT(@csv, LEN(@csv) -1))

SET @csv = 'SELECT ' + @csv + ' FROM ' + @tableName

-- for debugging: 
-- SELECT @csv

-- execute the SQL query
EXEC @csv
```

**Edit for MSSQL, 'EXEC' will truncate the @csv variable, if this is the case you'll have to use 2 variables (or more if @csv is longer than 2000)**

```
DECLARE @csvPartOne VARCHAR(500) = LEFT(@csv, 500)
DECLARE @csvPartTwo VARCHAR(MAX) = RIGHT(@csv, LEN(@csv) - 500)

-- execute the SQL query
EXEC (@csvPartOne + @csvPartTwo)
```

Comment: This solution is not for me because my table has about 100 fields, and I want to run the query: SELECT * FROM mytable.

Comment: @Rogér I updated my answer, let me know if it works out or not. I don't know what SQL language you're using